# Repairing a receiver sub-power supply and need to identify a TO-252 component for replacement (1510B T3330 T237)

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, identification, components

I have a receiver that, when trying to turn on, would shut off immediately.  Using a hair dryer allowed the receiver to turn on. After a bit of troubleshooting, I found some questionable solder connections, a faulty electrolytic cap (replaced the pair as the "good one" was below spec and the bad one measured at about 630uF versus rated 2200uF), and a component that, when warmed with an iron, allowed the receiver to operate normally. When cooled, the receiver would shut off immediately. On the board it is referenced as "IC39":

[image]

I need to find a replacement for this component that I am guessing is a voltage regulator. I have been looking for a few hours and am now trying this site.

[image]

[image]

Preparing the spot for a new chip:
[image][image]

2023-08-29
I received the substitute for the substitute of the existing voltage regulator.  It appears to have better current handling capability.
[image]
It came from Digikey which worked better than Mouser, for me.

Comment: What role does it play in the circuitry?  Barring that, are there any service manuals which happen to list IC39?  Could be a regulator, MOSFET, single/dual diode, BJT, etc.

Comment: Manufacturer will not ID the component as "they still service the equipment".  I believe it to be a voltage regulator but as the tracings are so small and other components around it are also non-identifiable, it is difficult to tell.

Comment: Here is a [forum post](https://www.homecinema-fr.com/forum/son-audio-amplificateurs-integres-homecinema/anthem-mrx310-mrx510-et-mrx710-2013-t30040701-1260.html) where someone had the same problem. They replaced it with a [NJM2845DL1-33-TE1](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/294/NJM2845_NJM2846_E-1917136.pdf) 3.3V LDO. I'm pretty sure it's not a NJM2845 on your board, but it might be some equivalent regulator.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Based on that I can at least take some voltage measurements as the device still "works" when it is warm.  It could help confirm the potential substitution.

Comment: When powered off, IC39 measures 5.18 VDC at the input and 3.27 VDC at the output.  While trying to turn on cold (and it cylces off) there is no change to the voltage.  When applying heat to the IC, the unit powers on but there is still no change to the voltage.  Based on the NJM2845DL1, it would seem there is a fault with the internal thermal protection.  So it appears to indeed be a voltage regulator but I still need specs even if I am to obtain a subtitute.

Comment: If heating the component changes the operation you might also suspect a bad solder joint that expands or contracts with temperature changes. You might try re-soldering all the pins and tab just to be sure. Occasionally you might even find SMT pads that lift off the board surface creating a hard to find open or intermittent connection.

Comment: Have seen vias corrode in the middle (due to hydraulic fluid contamination --> adsorbed water) and become intermittent and temperature-sensitive.  Also if the part gets really hot, consider a "flag" or "tab" of wire or copper tape soldered to the tab and sticking up into the air for a few percent more heatsinking.  Many of these LDOs run very hot.

Comment: All the solder tabs on IC39 were touched up and it made no difference to the operation.  I have the replacement part on order and will install when it comes in.  Yes, I have run into the pads lifting off and also cracks in boards.  In this case all were in good condition.

Comment: Since the component swap was unsuccessful, I will followup iwth Nedd's comment of finding another poor connection that must be in the vicinity of the regulator.

Comment: Just warming the board while shileding certain components leads me to believe there is a weak point in the tracing or a poor solder connection, which I am still trying to locate.

Answer (score 1):

So Nanash1 found a post with the exact problem where the chip was identified as: [NJM2845DL1-33-TE1](https://www.homecinema-fr.com/forum/son-audio-amplificateurs-integres-homecinema/anthem-mrx310-mrx510-et-mrx710-2013-t30040701-1260.html)

Turns out theirs is the exact same amplifier with the exact same voltage regulator problem. I will order the NJM2845DL1-33-TE1 and confirm.
Thanks to Nanash1!

2023-08-30: I installed a [BA33BC0FP](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/rohm-semiconductor/BA33BC0FP-E2/3663735), as it was listed as a substitute for the above regulator, and still no go.  Therefore, it has to be some other contact in the vicinity of this regulator.  Frustrating to say the least.